# No answer from Facebook chat when connecting through XMPP

Tags: node.js, xmpp, chat, facebook-chat

I'm using node-xmpp to connect to Facebook chat XMPP api.
I cannot find why, but sometimes everything is fine : I ask facebook for a connection with my ID (-@chat.facebook.com), my api_key, my access_token and the host (chat.facebook.com), and it answers me an online notification followed by presence messages.
But sometimes (many times in fact), I just don't have any answer from Facebook whereas I send the exact same request...

Have you ever experienced similar issues with Facebook?
Do you guys have an idea on what's going on?

Thanks a lot

S.